# Why is this Cocoa layout ambiguous?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I want to use layout constraints and create my UI programmatically. Here is a simple program that I'm hoping you can help me understand.  In Interface Builder, I simply took the defaults -- there is an `NSWindow` with its default `contentView`.  Below is all the code, and a screenshot.

I create a single button, and place it in the content view. Then I try to use constraints to make it fill the window. As you can see, it claims the layout is ambiguous. But when I click that button to "Exercise Ambiguity", nothing changes. The docs say it should choose a different possible layout.

I also think the content view is tightly surrounding the button and not filling the window, but I don't know how to force that with constraints.

```
// In AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSButton *_button;    
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

// In AppDelegate.m

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSView *contentView = (NSView*)_window.contentView;
    _button = [[NSButton alloc] init];
    _button.title = @"Test";

    _button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [contentView addSubview:_button];

    NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button, contentView);
    NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_button]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDict]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_button]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDict]];

    [contentView addConstraints:constraints];
    [_window visualizeConstraints:constraints];

    printf("Is layout ambiguous? %d\n", contentView.hasAmbiguousLayout);
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you pass nil instead of zero for metrics?

Answer (score 0):

What if you visualize constraints on a subsequent iteration of the run loop, for example with a timer or by clicking a button, after the layout engine has had a pass at it? It may just be ambiguous because the layout engine hasn’t solved the system yet.

**Edit:** I ran your code, and am seeing the same issue. I’m also stumped now.